# Trying To Add A Edit Function Into Todo List Program With Meteor JS?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor JS and I was following the official tutorial on their website.
I thought it would be nice to add an edit button to the original finished and delete buttons.
I can't seem to figure out how to add the functionality of editing the todo item. I have added the edit button itself via html but I just need to figure out how to add the functionality of actually editing the item itself.

Here is the javascript code:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      // Show newest tasks first
      return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // This function is called when the new task form is submitted
      var text = event.target.text.value;

      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date() // current time
      });

      // Clear form
      event.target.text.value = "";

      // Prevent default form submit
      return false;
    }
  });

  Template.task.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
      Tasks.update(this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}});
    },
    "click .delete": function () {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    },
    "click .edit": function () {
      Tasks.update(this._id, {});
    }
  });
}
```

Help Would Be Much Appreciated!

Comment: I am thinking you missed something while using it and official example for Todo has the editing for todo. Its just inline edit on each todo item.

Comment: He is talking about the tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/try

Comment: The way the full todos example does it is to always show the todo item text within an `input` element which is styled to look like plain text and then capture the `keydown` and `keyup` events to save any changes.